# How many elements of the form $a^{m_1} b^{n_1} a^{m_2} b^{n_2} a^{m_3} b^{n_3}$ in $G:=\langle a,b \mid a^2, b^4, (ab)^3 \rangle?$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to show that $G:=\langle a,b \mid a^2, b^4, (ab)^3 \rangle$ is of order at most 24. (To prove that it is a presentation of $S_4$.)

I thought of using the homomorphism $f$ sending $a$ to $(1 2)$ and $b$ to $(1 2 3 4)$. The image of this homomorphism generates $S_4$, and it satisfies the relations of $G$.

Hence the homomorphism $f$ extends to a homomorphism $f’$ making the following diagram commute

[image]

Claim: $f’$ is an isomorphism to its image $f’(G)=S_4$.

Since $f’$ is surjective and its image has order $24$, it suffices to show that $|G|\le 24$. Now, any word in $G$ in $a$ and $b$ can be written in the form $a^{m_1} b^{n_1} a^{m_2} b^{n_2} a^{m_3} b^{n_3}$, or $b^{n_1} a^{m_1} b^{n_2} a^{m_2} b^{n_3} a^{m_3} $ where $m_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $n_i\in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Now there is $2(2^3\times 4^3)=2(512)=1024$ elements, but since $(ab)^3=1$, then $G$’s elements should be way less than $1024$, but I am not sure how to show that. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think there is software to get the order of a presented group like yours.

Comment: OP should clarify, but I think they want an actual argument that the order is correct.

Comment: How can $f'$ be surjective and its image only have order $8$?

Comment: GAP is one such software, @coffeemath.

Comment: @Noobie sorry I meant 24.

Comment: Computers would do this using coset enumeration. But this example is small enough to do by hand. Use coset enumeration to  show that $|G:\langle b \rangle| = 6$, and then use $b^4=1$ to deduce $|G| \le 24$.

Comment: There are plenty of reductions to be made in your expressions. For example, in the first form $a^{m_1}b^{n_1}\cdots b^{n_3}$, you should not allow $m_1$ to be either $0$ or $1$; it should be $1$ (otherwise, you can write it in the second form). And you should not allow any of $n_1,m_2,n_2,m_3,n_3$ to be zero unless the remaining ones are also zero.

Comment: Could you edit your question? Yesterday, by mistake instead of upvoting I downvoted ( mobile phone). I cannot change my bite  to the correct one before re-edit. Sorry for all the commotion.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258620/what-are-relations-of-s-4-if-generators-are-a-12-b-1234/

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc no worries! I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks. I've just corrected my voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution results from carrying a coset enumeration by hand and then translating it back into standard mathematical language.

Let $H = \langle b \rangle$. We will prove that
$$G = H \cup Ha \cup Hab \cup Haba \cup Hab^2 \cup Hab^2a.$$
This shows that $|G:H| \le 6$ and since $b^4=1 \Rightarrow |H| \le 4$, this gives $|G| \le 24$, as required.

Denote the union of these six cosets of $H$ by $X$. To show that $X=G$, it is enough to show that $xg \in X$ for all $x \in X$ andd $g \in G$ and, by an easy inductive argument, it is enough to show that $xa \in X$ and $xb \in X$, for $x \in  \{ 1,a,ab,aba,ab^2,ab^2a \}$. So we'll do that!

$1a \in Ha$, $1b \in H$.

$aa=1 \in H$, $ab \in Hab$.

$aba \in Haba$,   $abb \in Hab^2$.

$abaa \in Hab$, $abab = b^{-1}a \in Ha$.

$ab^2a \in Hab^2a$, $ab^2b = ab^{-1} = baba \in Haba$.

$ab^2a^2 \in Hab^2$, $ab^2ab = (aba)(abab) = b^{-1}ab^{-1}b^{-1}a=b^{-1}ab^2a  \in Hab^2a$.

Comment: I see now that this is virtually identical to my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258620/) form a year ago!